# Peak of a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Provide me an example of a sequence that has finite number of peaks.

Definition: Let $<a_n>$ be a sequence then $a_m$ is peak point or a peak of $<a_n>$ if $a_m \ge a_n$ $\forall n \ge m$

My Attempt:

I know an example of a sequence
$$a_n =  \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
{1\over n} + 1 & \text{for } n \leq 5\\
n & \text{for } n >5
\end{array}\right.$$ that has finite number of peak points.
But it does not satisfy definition of peaks. Please help me.

Comment: The definition says that a "peak" is an $a_m$ not less than all subsequent $a_n$ (including $a_m$ itself). So, take any increasing sequence or any sequence that is usually increasing except at finitely many points.

Comment: Wouldn't every point of a constant sequence be a peak by your definition?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to construct such sequences based on an original bounded sequence which is monotone increasing. For instance, $a_n = \arctan(n)$ is one, bounded above by $\pi/2$. So you can specify particular $a_i$ such that $(a_i)$ is a finite monotone decreasing sequence and $a_i > \pi/2 \; \forall i$. Then each $a_i$ specified is a peak per the definition provided.

Example:

$$a_n = \left\{ \begin{matrix}
10 & n=1 \\
9 & n=2 \\
8 & n=3 \\
\arctan(n) & n \ge 4
\end{matrix} \right.$$

Comment: Please remove my confusion in " My Attempt "